# Laplace Equation on Infinite Strip - Integral Representation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, conformal-geometry

I'm looking to solve Laplace's equation on the infinite strip $(x,y)\in(0,1)\times(0,\infty)$ with mixed boundary conditions identical to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177875/solve-laplaces-equation-inside-a-semi-infinite-strip) question:

$$\Delta u=0$$
$$u_x(0,y)=u_x(1,y)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
The answer provided there is from a separation-of-variables approach, but I am interested in an integral representation if possible (mainly for numerical evaluation because $f$ is given numerically). Several examples where there are Dirichlet conditions on the boundaries (rather than Nuemann conditions) have integral representations such as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327384/how-to-solve-2d-laplace-equation-over-an-infinite-rectangular-strip-bounded-on) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065485/fourier-transform-laplace-equation-on-infinite-strip-weird-solution-involvin). With Dirchlet conditions, one can employ the conformal mapping $z\mapsto\cos(z)$ (mapping the strip to a half plane) and use the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) to get an integral representation. However, the Poisson kernel does not apply for mixed-boundary conditions like those above. I would appreciate any assistance determining if an integral representation exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the separation of variables solution, there is a way to sum the series
$$
        u(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n\cos(n\pi x)e^{-n\pi y}.
$$
$u(x,0)=f(x)$ determines the coefficients $A_n$:
$$
           f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n\cos(n\pi x)
$$
$$
         \int_0^1 f(x)\cos(n\pi x)dx = A_n\int_0^1\cos(n\pi x)^2dx 
$$
$$
         A_n = \frac{\int_0^1 f(x)\cos(n\pi x)dx}{\int_0^1\cos^2(n\pi x)dx}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
    u(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\int_0^1f(x')\cos(n\pi x')dx'}{\int_0^1\cos^2(n\pi x')dx'}\cos(n\pi x)e^{-n\pi y} \\
   = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2\int_0^1f(x')\cos(n\pi x')\cos(n\pi x)e^{-n\pi y}dx' \\
   = 2\int_0^1f(x')\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos(n\pi x')\cos(n\pi x)e^{-n\pi y}dx' \\
   = 2\int_0^1f(x')\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\cos(n\pi(x'-x))+\cos(n\pi(x+x'))e^{-n\pi y}dx' \\
   = 2\Re\int_0^1f(x')\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(e^{in\pi(x'-x)}+e^{in\pi(x'+x)})e^{-n\pi y}dx'
$$
Now it comes down to summing a geometric series, which I'll leave to you.